# Why transform my package.json ?? when i was "npm i", "npm uni"

Tags: node.js, npm-install, package.json

[image]

Sometime my package.json transform when i was "npm install" or "npm uninstall".
Please tell me what is causing this and how to fix it.
I'm manually removing the whitespace right now.

Comment: You should not touch your package.json file unless you really need to. Let npm handle it for you. To create a package.json file run `npm init`. To update a package.json file either do `npm install` or `npm uninstall` or `npm update`. The file is meant for use by npm. What's causing this behavior is **this is the normal way it should work**.

Comment: @slebetman I think it's fair to assume that the `npm` commands should not insert tons of whitespace

Comment: I haven't touched the package.json file directly. However, when I run npm i or uni, I get a space like that.